# Killing All Threads in Python

Tags: python

I have a python script that will constant ping some IPs and print the results to the screen. 
But I want to terminte the script via a key press (ideally using the q key or via a ctrl c) and then for all threads to be terminated.

What is the best way to achieve this ? My code is below...

```
import os
import re
import time
import sys
import subprocess
import Queue
import threading

def screen_output(x, y, text):
     sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (x, y, text))
     sys.stdout.flush()

class pingo:

    def __init__(self,hosts):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.all_results = {}
        self.hosts = hosts

    def send_ping(self,q,ip):
        self.q.put(self.record_results(ip))

    def record_results(self,ip):
        ping_count = 0

        host_results = {
            "device" : None,
            "sent_count" : 0,
            "success_count": 0,
            "fail_count": 0,
            "failed_perc": 0,
            "curr_status": None
            }


        while True:
            rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip], stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
            ping_count += 1

            # update stats

            sent_count = host_results['sent_count']
            success_count = host_results['success_count']
            fail_count = host_results['fail_count']
            failed_perc = host_results['failed_perc']
            curr_status = host_results['curr_status']

            sent_count += 1

            if rc == 0:
                success_count += 1
                curr_status = "Successful Response"
            else:
                fail_count += 1
                curr_status = "Request Timed Out"

            failed_perc =  ( fail_count / sent_count ) * 100

            host_results.update({'failed_perc': failed_perc, 'fail_count': fail_count, 'success_count': success_count, 'curr_status': curr_status, 'sent_count': sent_count})
            time.sleep(0.5)
            self.all_results.update({ip:host_results})
            screen_output(0,0,self.all_results)
        return True

    def go(self):
        for i in self.hosts:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_ping, args = (self.q,i))
            #t.daemon = True
            t.start()

p =  pingo(["8.8.8.8"])
p.go()
```

Edit : Ive tried adding a global ALIVE flag as suggested but this still fails to kill the threads via a CRTL-C.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import Queue
import threading
import signal

def screen_output(x, y, text):
     sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (x, y, text))
     sys.stdout.flush()

class pingo:

    def __init__(self,hosts):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.all_results = {}
        self.hosts = hosts
        self.ALIVE = True

    def signal_handler(self,signal, frame):
        self.ALIVE = False

    def send_ping(self,q,ip):
        self.q.put(self.record_results(ip))

    def record_results(self,ip):
        ping_count = 0

        host_results = {
            "device" : None,
            "sent_count" : 0,
            "success_count": 0,
            "fail_count": 0,
            "failed_perc": 0,
            "curr_status": None
            }


        while self.ALIVE:
            try:
                rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip], stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
                ping_count += 1

                # update stats

                sent_count = host_results['sent_count']
                success_count = host_results['success_count']
                fail_count = host_results['fail_count']
                failed_perc = host_results['failed_perc']
                curr_status = host_results['curr_status']

                sent_count += 1

                if rc == 0:
                    success_count += 1
                    curr_status = "Successful Response"
                else:
                    fail_count += 1
                    curr_status = "Request Timed Out"

                failed_perc =  ( fail_count / sent_count ) * 100

                host_results.update({'failed_perc': failed_perc, 'fail_count': fail_count, 'success_count': success_count, 'curr_status': curr_status, 'sent_count': sent_count})
                time.sleep(0.5)
                self.all_results.update({ip:host_results})
                screen_output(0,0,self.all_results)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.signal_handler)
        return True


    def go(self):
        for i in self.hosts:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_ping, args = (self.q,i))
            #t.daemon = True
            t.start()

p =  pingo(["8.8.8.8"])
p.go()
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a global flag `ALIVE` (or not necessarily global, you can use a dict or a class attribute), bind to SIGINT and change it on that:

```
import signal

ALIVE = True

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global ALIVE
    ALIVE = False

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

and then simply change your loop to:

```
def record_results(self,ip):
    # some code
    while ALIVE:
        # some code
```

That way it will quit gracefully (some time after receiving the signal).

Comment: How about:**try:** stuff; and **except KeyboardInterrupt:**

Comment: @Marichyasana It's essentially the same; you can just turn off `global ALIVE` in the `except KeyboardInterrupt` clause.

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion but this still didn't appear to work. Ive updated the question.

Comment: @felix001 the reason it fails is because you're merging the advice in the answer and that in the comments. To do it with signal handlers, put the `signal.signal` line outside of any try/except block (it sets up a callback function for if you receive that signal). To do it the try/except way, set `self.ALIVE` directly in the `except` block (or call `self.signal_handler()` rather than `signal.signal`). The way you're doing it now, you need to receive Ctrl-C once to bind the callback, then another time to actually call it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the top FAQ in Python.  There are basically two ways to do that.

1. (Graceful way) See @freakish's answer.
2. (Lazy way) Turn on the "daemon" flag of all the worker threads.  See this Q&A for example: [Understanding Python daemon threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470235/understanding-python-daemon-threads)